# Set font for Devanagari Characters in Doom Emacs

Tags: fonts

Running Doom Emacs 2.0.9 on Emacs 27.1.

I want to always display Devanagari characters in a specific font (Sarpanch). This font is installed on my computer and I can use it in all other applications like Libre Office, etc.

How do I achieve this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`(set-fontset-font t 'devanagari "Noto Sans Devanagari")`

does the job. Of course, replace 'Noto Sans Devanagari' with whatever font you prefer (and ensure that it is installed on your system).

Comment: You should be able to accept your answer by now (assuming that it *does* answer the question...).