# Doom Emacs - Setting Font for Devanagari characters

Tags: fonts

I had faced the similar problem earlier and found a solution myself [here](https://emacs.stackexchange.com/questions/64171/set-font-for-devanagari-characters-in-doom-emacs). But I am stumped now.

I am running Doom Emacs 3.0.0 on Emacs 27.2 on Gnome 40.4.

In my `config.el`, there is:

```
(set-fontset-font t 'devanagari "Eczar")
```

I have installed Eczar font. `font-counsel` shows Eczar as an option. `set-frame-font` shows multiple Eczar entries --- I guess, one each for a variant. I can select any of these and the change is reflected immediately. I can do Options -> Set Main Font and select Eczar. And like in the previous case, the change is reflected immediately.

But that setting in `config.el` has no effect. I can not get only Devanagari characters to display in Eczar (or any other) font.

`describe-char` shows the font Gotu. I had used that earlier.

How do I solve this problem?

Comment: Does "Eczar" appear as a choice if you click  on `Options-> Set Default Font`? If it does, can you select it? Does it work?

Comment: @NickD Thanks. Yes. It does show Eczar. It shows several variants like Eczar Regular, Medium, etc. I can select any of these. And the text changes accordingly. But that changes it for *all* character sets. I wanted that font *only* for Devanagari characters.

Comment: Yes, I meant it as a sanity check, not as a solution.

Comment: @NickD Oh OK. I will update my question to include this piece of information.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should in general do fontset changes in `window-setup-hook` (for normal frames) and `server-after-make-frame-hook` (for client frames).  Therefore, I suggest that you try the following:

```lisp
(defun my-customize-default-fontset ()
  "Customize the default fontset."
  (set-fontset-font t 'devanagari "Eczar"))

(add-hook 'window-setup-hook #'my-customize-default-fontset)
(add-hook 'server-after-make-frame-hook #'my-customize-default-fontset)
```

Comment: Perfect. That did the trick. Thanks!!