# Devanagari script in org-table

Tags: org-mode, fonts, org-table, input-method

Org-table works as expected when it comes to English characters.

```
| a | b | c | d | e |
| f | g | h | i | j |
| k | l | m | n | o |
| p | q | r | s | t |
| u | v | w | x | y |
| z |   |   |   |   |
```

However, if I try to do the same with Devanagari script (itrans inscript), table columns don't get aligned properly.

```
| क | ख | ग | घ | ङ |
| च | छ | ज | झ | ञ |
| ट | ठ | ड | ढ | ण |
| त | थ | द | ध | न |
| प | फ | ब | भ | म |
```

Is there a way to align columns where cell values are in Devanagari font? I tried
`(set-face-attribute 'org-table nil  :inherit 'fixed-pitch)` which seems to have no effect.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> However, if I try to do the same with Devanagari script (itrans inscript), table columns don't get aligned properly.

Use [`valign`](https://elpa.gnu.org/packages/valign.html) from GNU ELPA.

From the blurb

> This package provides visual alignment for Org Mode, Markdown and table.el tables on GUI Emacs. It can properly align tables containing variable-pitch font, CJK characters and images. Meanwhile, the text-based alignment generated by Org mode (or Markdown mode) is left untouched.

For the sake of demonstration, this is what I did

1. Install `valign` with `M-x pacakge-refresh-contents` and `M-x package-install RET valign RET`
2. Add the following to your init file (or `eval` it)

```
(add-hook 'org-mode-hook #'valign-mode)
```

3. Copy your `devanagari` table to an `org` file.

```
| क | ख | ग | घ | ङ |
| च | छ | ज | झ | ञ |
| ट | ठ | ड | ढ | ण |
| त | थ | द | ध | न |
| प | फ | ब | भ | म |
```

4. Do `M-x revert-buffer` when in above `org` buffer
5. Mission accomplished.

What you see below is the screenshot of *before* and *after* `valign` is activated.

[image: An org buffer with indic script without and with valign-mode]

`valign` is *disabled* when the table size exceeds a specific threshold.  So, if you happen to notice that some of your tables are mis-aligned, even when `valign-mode` is ON, then you may have to configure `valign-max-table-size` to a higher value.

For the sake of record, and if  you haven't already noticed ... *You DO NOT need to do all the jugglery with fonts and their widths suggested in the other responses.*  This is because the `valign` library measures pixel-width when doing alignment.

Comment: Yeah your answers are probably better than mine. Upvoted. Unfortunately like so much that's new in emacs it completely undocumented 

Comment: this works like a charm, thank you!

Answer (score 2):

You need to find a fixed–pitch Devanagari font where the Devanagari glyphs are exactly the same width as the glyphs for ASCII characters.

Comment: Now I remember I tried this approach some time ago and had to abandon because it did not work. Perhaps the fixed-pitch font I chose was incorrect. Would appreciate font recommendation if you have worked with it.

Comment: No, I don’t write in Devanagari so I don’t have any fonts to recommend.

Answer (score 2):

**This is *not a answer* to the original question, but *a response to the comment* https://emacs.stackexchange.com/a/71562/31220.**

**FWIW, the answer is in https://emacs.stackexchange.com/a/71569/31220.**

*PS: I don't have 50+ reputation to `Add a comment`, so I will go with  `Post your answer` as an expedient.*

---

FWIW, the [`elisp` code there](https://emacs.stackexchange.com/a/71562/31220) does `transliteration` from `English`-*letters* to `Devanagari`-*letters*.  The code that does the `transliteration` part is this

```
(execute-kbd-macro inp)
```

Instead of using `execute-kbd-macro`, it would be much cleaner to use `indian-translate-region`.

Let me clarify what I mean ...

1. Copy the table below to a temp buffer

```
| ka  | kha  | ga | gha | ~Na |
| cha | chha | ja | jha | ~na |
| Ta  | Tha  | Da | Dha | Na  |
| ta  | tha  | da | dha | na  |
| pa  | pha  | ba | bha | ma  |
```

2. Mark the whole table with `C-SPC` etc etc
3. Then do

```
M-: (indian-dev-itrans-v5-decode-region (region-beginning) (region-end))
```

4. You will get `transliterate`-d text as below.

[image: Trasliterating from English to Devanagari]

For the sake of record,

1. In the above example, one moved from `English` to `Devanagari`.  You can also `transliterate` from `Devanagari` to `English` using `indian-dev-itrans-v5-encode-region`.
2. Transliteration works NOT just for `Devanagari`, but for any `indic` script, say `Tamil`.  See the above `encode`, `decode` functions or dive in to `indian-translate-region` for more details.

Answer (score 1):

Here's one recipe for getting fixed-width Devanagari glyphs (with limitations):

- download a fixed-width Devanagari font: I found one [here](https://github.com/monotty/fonts/blob/master/.resources/monotty-dev2.ttf).
- assuming you are on Linux, create a `/usr/share/fonts/monotty` directory and copy the downloaded file there. You will need to use `sudo` (or otherwise be root) for this step. This is needed if you want the font to be available to every user of the system. Alternatively, you can install in `~/.fonts`: no need to be root, but only you get to use it.
- Refresh the font cache **[1]**: `fc-cache -v`
- Add this to your init file **[2]**: `(set-fontset-font t 'devanagari "Monotty")`
- Restart emacs to pick up the new font.

Now press TAB on your table above and you should get proper alignment.

If that does not work, check all the steps carefully and use `C-u C-x =` on a Devanagari glyph and check the font that it reports. It should read:     `ftcrhb:- OS -Monotty-regular-normal-normal-*-13-*-*-*-m-0-iso10646-1 (#x2D)` or something similar. Without the `monotty` font, I was getting this instead:     `ftcrhb:-GNU -Denemo-regular-normal-normal-*-15-*-*-*-*-0-iso10646-1 (#x64E)` although it may be different in individual cases, depending on what fonts are installed.

**Limitations**:

- Although the Devanagari glyphs are fixed-width, they do *NOT* have the same width as other glyphs (Roman glyphs e.g.), so you cannot mix Devanagari glyphs and Roman glyphs in the same column, although having some columns consisting exlusively of Roman glyphs and some other columns exclusively of Devanagari glyphs should work.
- The Devanagari strings in a column have to consist of the same number of glyphs, otherwise some columns have more spaces than others and the *space* glyph has a different width, destroying the alignment. It would be nice to find a monospaced Devanagari font whose glyphs have the same width as the glyphs of the other fonts that make up a table as @db48x recommends in his answer, but I don't know of one.
- Maybe others... I have only tested the table you provide plus simple extensions like those described in the previous bullet.

---

**[1]** @db48x in his comment states that font caches are per-user. The [Fedora docs](https://docs.fedoraproject.org/en-US/quick-docs/fonts/#unpackaged) say to run `sudo fc-cache -v` for system font installation. I haven't tested enough to make sure that @db48x is correct, but I'm taking him at his word and assuming that the docs are not quite correct.

**[2]** I found this in [this Emacs SE question](https://emacs.stackexchange.com/questions/64171/set-font-for-devanagari-characters-in-doom-emacs/64173#64173), but with a different font that AFAIK is not monospaced.

Comment: You need not be root to install a font. Just copy the font file into `~/.fonts` instead of `/usr/share/fonts`. You won’t need to be root to run `fc-cache` either, as the caches are stored per–user.

Comment: OK - fixed it up a bit. Thanks!

Comment: You can check `man fc-cache` for a hint: “%cachedir%/*-%arch%.cache-%version%: These files are generated by fc-cache and contain maps from file names to font properties” along with a pointer to `/usr/share/doc/fontconfig/fontconfig-user.html` which explains that “The default directory is ``$XDG_CACHE_HOME/fontconfig''”.

Comment: thanks, will give this font a try. ideally I would want column width to adjust according to the largest string on that column. will report back (I am using mac btw) how it goes.

Comment: I don't think you are going to get that with this font: see the second limitation I mention.

Comment: you're right. `valign-mode`, which I didn't know existed, does the job!

Comment: You might want to write it up (with more detail of course) as an answer. It might be of interest to others with the same problem.

Answer (score 1):

This may not be exactly an answer. And its an acquired taste.

I write my files in roman thus

```
| ka  | kha  | ga | gha | ~Na |
| cha | chha | ja | jha | ~na |
| Ta  | Tha  | Da | Dha | Na  |
| ta  | tha  | da | dha | na  |
| pa  | pha  | ba | bha | ma  |
```

And *generate*

```
| क  | ख  | ग | घ | ङ |
| च | छ | ज | झ | ञ |
| ट  | ठ  | ड | ढ | ण  |
| त  | थ  | द | ध | न  |
| प  | फ  | ब | भ | म  |
```

The generating code is

```
(setq rpm-input-method "devanagari-itrans")

(defun rpm-apply-input-method ()
  "buffer to buffer apply input method with buffering windowing stuff mixed up"
  (interactive)
  (let* ((inp (buffer-substring-no-properties (point-min) (point-max)))
     (filename (file-name-nondirectory (buffer-file-name)))
     (outname (concat (file-name-sans-extension filename)
                   "-hi"
                   (file-name-extension filename t)))
     (p))
    (switch-to-buffer-other-frame outname)
    (save-excursion
      (save-window-excursion
    (setq buffer-file-coding-system 'utf-8)
    (set-input-method rpm-input-method t)
    (setq p (point))
    (erase-buffer)
    (execute-kbd-macro inp)))
    (goto-char p)
    (other-frame 1)))

(global-set-key [f4] 'rpm-apply-input-method)
```

Comment: hmm...generated output still seems misaligned tho. My problem is not with the typing Devanagari part but that ugly looking table :)